# Non-responsive Bootstrap 3 - removing max-width breaks mobile

Tags: css, mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am tasked with fixing the problem on this site and I cannot figure it out. The site is supposed to be non-responsive. There is extra space on the right side of the layout on small screen sizes - the site breaks. I cannot fix it without removing

```
max-width: none !important
```

from the CSS, but this is the very code that makes the site non-responsive. The person seems to have followed the official Bootstrap 3 directions for creating non-responsive, so I don't understand why it's breaking. I'm missing something. Here's the site:

http://dev.codeandcursor.com/gunnar_bootstrap/didyouseethis/

Comment: not easy to understand what you mean with extra space. The grid will have a padding of 30px on both side (-15px (margin) on your .row and 15 pixels padding on your .col-xs-* classes). This should be visible on both sides. Could you possible add an image of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set body a `min-width`

```
body {
    min-width:1237px;
}
```